# NokiaHere maps rendering issue after upgrading to 3.1 version

Tags: javascript, dictionary, here-api, tangram

I am migrating Here javascript libraries (**3.0** to **3.1**) on an **Ember.js v2.18** project because the v3.0 Here libraries don't support **apiKey authentication** (appCode and appId will no longer be generated).

When trying to create a map object with the following code :

`let map = new H.Map(this.$('#map')[0], defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map);`

the following error occurs : `Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:http://localhost:4200/0d8aefdf-160f-47ca-8672-04d73de528eb: e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function TypeError: "e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function".`

Can someone explain to me the meaning of this issue or any workaround to render the map correctly ?

Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: Try please instead of vector the raster engine see please the example on https://jsfiddle.net/ufz3w5tm/

Note on mapsjs-core-legacy.js and mapsjs-service-legacy.js in HTML section
Note on engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D by map defination

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I am already using raster mode to display the map..

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport after adding the engineType I have the following error : x.H.map.render.p2d is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try please instead of vector the raster engine see please the example on jsfiddle.net/ufz3w5tm Note on mapsjs-core-legacy.js and mapsjs-service-legacy.js in HTML section Note on engineType: H.Map.EngineType.P2D by map defination

Comment: Are the mapsjs-core-legacy.js and mapsjs-service-legacy.js also included in your application. The message "x.H.map.render.p2d is undefined" indicates that these necessary libraries are not being loaded in your application.

Comment: Yes they are included !

Comment: I just tried the new javascript sdk version (3.1.12.0), now I can render the map but cannot perform routing request, I have the following error : z is not defined.